# Return the embedded documents that match the query

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a model like this

```
{
    _id: '5a7745529c69b22fe5d6f321',
    array: [{
        name: 'a',
        something: 'something1'
    },{
        name: 'b',
        something: 'something2'
    },{
        name: 'a',
        something: 'something2'
    }]
}
```

And I need to get all the embedded documents with name `a`

```
The output must be
    [{
        name: 'a',
        something: 'something1'
    },{
        name: 'a',
        something: 'something2'
    }]
```

when I use unwind it's giving the array key for each document. I want the output exactly as above. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @JohnnyHK . I think you do understand the output I expect. I don't want my result to be wrapped in an object and then  the array attached to a key.           I expect the array directly.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
 { $unwind : “$array” },
 { $match : { name : “a” } },
 { $project : { _id : 0, array : 1 } }
 ])
```